# MySQL Filter Between Date in Different Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 1 table `transactions` with column like this:

```
id | id_items | date      | total
--- ---------- ----------- -------
1   it2        2020-09-01  10
2   it2        2020-09-02  15
3   it4        2020-09-03  5
4   it4        2020-09-04  15
5   it2        2020-10-11  10
6   it4        2020-10-12  5
7   it4        2020-10-13  20
8   it2        2020-10-14  5
```

I want to show the total result (`SUM`) between different range date (Sep and Oct) in 2 column GROUP BY `id_items` like this:

```
id_items | total(sept) | total(oct)
--------- ------------- ------------
it2       25            10
it4       20            25
```

Can you give me the MySQL query to solve my problem? Thank you.

Comment: @HarryWardana I need MySQL query code not PHP, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT id_items,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(t.date) = 9, t.total, 0)) AS sept_total,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(t.date) = 10, t.total, 0)) AS oct_total
FROM transactions t
GROUP BY id_items
```

The idea is to group by `id_items` and then `SUM()` the aggregate totals conditionally depending on month of transaction. The above is fairly simplistic and assumes there are no transactions before 2020. If your data spans multiple years you'd need to account for that in your condition somewhere, e.g., `WHERE YEAR(t.date) = 2020`

Comment: Thank you @billynoah, it's work and what I need. 